# Php Javascript Image Upload and Edit

Tags: javascript, php, image, upload, edit

i'm looking for a Php / Javascript example script which can help me and be the base to build a tool for uploading images and than drag/rotate/scale and position them under a mask / frame.
Similar to tools used in custom photo print sites.
Any help?

Comment: why dont you search on google rather than posting here?

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking to learn how to code an uploader yourself, there are a number of good tutorials you can find. [Here is a basic one](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/). You can also find some pre-built ones [here](http://zurb.com/playground/ajax-upload) and [here](http://digitarald.de/project/fancyupload/). You can also find jQuery plugins that will do it for you [here](http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) and [here](http://www.uploadify.com/).

For the image manipulation, you can learn how to code one [here](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/04/05/image-manipulation-with-jquery-and-php-gd/) and [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/image-resizing-made-easy-with-php/). Or you can use a pre-built one that can be found [here](http://adeelejaz.com/blog/jquery-image-resize-plugin-v2/).

I know a lot of people don't like giving answer for things that you can find easily on a search engine. So I recommend next time explaining a little more if you have searched for something but cannot find what you are looking for. If you are simply asking for recommendations before doing a search yourself, odds are this will get locked before you can get any answers as they will all be subjective.

Comment: +1 For answering the question instead of simply referring the OP to Google.

Answer (score 0):

please try this example some as like your requirement

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" id="file">
<div id="preview"></div>
<br>
<a href="#" id="counter"><- counter</a>
    <select id="degree">
        <option>90</option>
        <option>45</option>
    </select>
<a href="#" id="clockwise">clockwise -></a>
<hr>
<button type="submit">save image</button>
```

css

```
#preview img {
max-height: 300px;
max-width: 300px;
}
```

script

```
$('a').click(function(){
var a = $('img').getRotateAngle();
var d = Math.abs($('#degree').val());

if($(this).attr('id') == 'counter'){
   //d = -Math.abs(+a - +d);
    d = a - d;
}
else{d = +a + +d;}

$('img').rotate({animateTo:d});
});

/* image preview */
$('#file').change(function(){
var oFReader = new FileReader();
oFReader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
console.log(this.files[0]);
oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
    $('#preview').html('<img src="'+oFREvent.target.result+'">');
};
});
```

and check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/AxRJh/